# Double cross product in 2D

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, cross-product, clifford-algebras

Hello I have a question about a double cross product, appearing in centrifugal force
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{F}_{centrifugal} = -m \boldsymbol{\omega} \times [\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}] \, .
\end{align*}
Is there an option to write this for 2D (maybe using bivectors?)?

Comment: Why would you want to? The cross product is (nearly always) a 3D concept.

Comment: Because I read that the more common formula $\frac{mv^2}{r}$ would be a special case of it. I wanted to consider this

Comment: Okay and to the motivation in general. You are right that this is usual a 3D concept but of course one often considers 2D where such expressions appear. A centrifugal force appears for example in a simple pendulum. Furthermore an implementation starts often with a 2D problem. Therefore it is useful to think about the 2D relation to check for example the dimensions of the matrices in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the back-cab rule as following$$\mathbf{F}_{centrifugal} = -m \boldsymbol{\omega} \times [\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}]=-m((\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{\omega}-|\boldsymbol{\omega}|^2\boldsymbol{r})=m|\boldsymbol{\omega}|^2r-m(\boldsymbol{r}\cdot \boldsymbol{\omega})\boldsymbol{\omega}$$